# java-joda datetime classes (current system time)?

Tags: java, c#, jodatime

I'm "Converting" some c# code to java and I've come to a point where things get weird.
I'm using the joda LocalTime  object as I'm dealing with time comparison only.

In c# to get the current system time we use the following code:

```
DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay //returns Timespan as wanted
```

But in Java-joda I can't find such thing and I'm forced to the following:

```
LocalTime nowLocalTime=new LocalTime();
LocalTime currenTime=new LocalTime(nowLocalTime.getHourOfDay(),nowLocalTime.getMinuteOfHour(),00);
```

Is there an alternative to that, a much sweeter way to do this? (I must pack it into LocalTime to make the use of the .Compare method).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking for [`LocalTime.now()`](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/LocalTime.html#now())

Comment: Believe me, I would have never find it, tnx

Comment: @esunic: Why not? THe first thing you should do with this sort of question is read the documentation.